# .net: Setting a method to public gives an error. Setting it to private returns an error

Tags: c#

[class code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc348689f54f2bc291bc5013262c20da)

[form code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/681d831b6abab2bdb70132610d665a02)

homework assignment is to create a class and create a windows form that uses methods defined in the class. Here's his finished code.

```
class HappyBirthday {

    //====================
    //  CLASS VARIABLES
    //====================
    private int numberOfPresents;
    private string birthdayMessage;
    private bool birthdayParty;

    //===========================
    //  DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    //===========================
    public HappyBirthday()
    {
        numberOfPresents = 0;
        birthdayParty = false;
    }

    //===========================
    //      METHOD
    //===========================
    private string getMessage(string givenName)
    {

        string theMessage;

        theMessage = "Happy Birthday " + givenName + "\n";
        theMessage += "Number of presents = ";
        theMessage += numberOfPresents.ToString() + "\n";

        if (birthdayParty == true) {
            theMessage += "Hope you enjoy the party!";
        }
        else {
            theMessage += "No party = sorry!";
        }

        return theMessage;
    }

    //================================
    //      READ AND WRITE PROPERTY
    //================================
    public string MyProperty {
        get { return birthdayMessage; }

        set { birthdayMessage = getMessage(value); }
    }

    //================================
    //     WRITE-ONLY PROPERTY
    //================================
    public int PresentCount {
        set { numberOfPresents = value; }
    }

    public bool hasParty {
        set { birthdayParty = value; }
    }

}
```

Well according to his code, string getMessage is private. Setting it to private makes it give an error on my form code button_1 "Inaccessible due to its protection level"

So I set it to public. That returns another error.

"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'givenName' of 'HappyBirthday.getMessage(string)"

Comment: Post the code, not the links

Comment: However, accessing the class method from another class (Form) you need to set that method with the public keyword. After that, if the method requires a parameter (the name) you should call it passing the parameter required IE: _HappyBirthday.getMessage("Herbert");_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that "generates" the birthday message is `private` (which means it's only visible/accessible to the class it's defined in), it should be accessed via the `MyProperty` property.

In your `Form1` class, change this:

```
MessageBox.Show( birthdayMessage.getMessage());
```

Into

```
MessageBox.Show(birthdayMessage.MyProperty);
```

And finally, the message is generated with a parameter for `name` (who the message is going to be for). You can `set` `MyProperty` property first, and it will generate the birthday for that name. So:

```
birthdayMessage.MyProperty = "Herbert";
var message = birthdayMessage.MyProperty; //<-- this now contains the full message
```

Comment: "Right now, your `HappyBirthday` is not visible to the `Form1` class" - assuming they are in the same project Form1 will be able to see HappyBirthday which is internal

Comment: tyvm. Pretty sure the teacher made an error because his assignments give us step by step lines so I just followed along the assignment and ended up with the code provided in the links. changing birthdayMessage.getMessage(); to birthdayMessage.MyProperty fixed it.

Comment: Why @john? This is a homework assignment, if the teacher intends to teach him calculated properties and backing fields, I am not really in a position to change the application's requirements?

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem is the call of the function:

```
 public string getMessage (string givenName)
```

The method needs a String given to it upon calling it but you call it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show( birthdayMessage.getMessage());
```

When changing the call to

```
MessageBox.Show( birthdayMessage.getMessage("Clay"));
```

it should work.

Comment: I think OP's teacher wanted to demonstrate backing fields and calculated properties. Changing the `getMessage` access modifier is taking a shortcut.

Comment: True, didn't take that into account. Thanks for pointing out :)